# Como utilizar senitize_sql_like junto com ilike

Tags: aplicação-web, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estou com dificuldade em utilizar o **senitize_sql_like**, junto com o **ilike**.

Quando o utilizo, a consulta não está retornando o valor esperado, segue implementação utilizada:

```
scope :brand_name_by_content, -> (brand, sna)
{sna.top_contents.where(sanitize_sql_like("content ilike '%#
{Brand.find(brand[0]).name}%'"))}
```

Comment: consegue incluir o que ele está retornando, o que você esperava que ele retornasse e a estrutura do seu db? aproveite e [faça o tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)!

Comment: para incluir mais dados, altere sua pergunta clicando em [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/328655/edit).

Comment: já consegui resolver, estava errado a chamada do sanitize.